# Error with z values in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, 3d-analyst

Although the input data has z values the tool "Adjust 3D z values" in ModelBuilder gives

> `ERROR 000245: The input feature class must have z values`

A multipoint feature gets intersected with a polygon feature and then the intersected multipoints get elevated with "Adjust 3D z value".
I have already set the properties of every feature in the model to "z-values: Enabled" or "z-values: Same as Input" but this doesn't help. As the model is very big it is not possible to post a readable screenshot.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop Advanced with 3D-analyst.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to test. You say it has Z values. A feature class can be Z aware but have no Z values. So first thing to test is does your point dataset actually have a number for its Z value? You mention that it is a multipoint dataset. May be its a bug in the tool (I've personally never used it), may be it only accepts single part datasets? Try exploding them into their single parts?

Comment: As the multipoint feature class has a huge amount of points it is not useful to convert it into single part features as explained [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n00000005000000#GUID-F6DBC0D7-E2D0-4F2E-8B27-F2C563439150). When visualized in ArcScene the multipoint feature class does have z values.

Comment: Can you provide a sample to see if others can run the tool on it?

Comment: How do I do that? I cannot provide the whole input data (big DEM etc.) with the model.

Comment: I was just thinking of you doing nothing more than selecting some of the points and export them out to a separate shapefile and zip it up then distribute via dropbox or Google drive what ever you use?

Comment: Ok, here is a part of my multipart feature:
http://www.file-upload.net/download-9875428/Extract_Multipoints.zip.html
When viewed in 3D-view ArcCatalog it does seem to have z values...